# Why I cannot receive data from a CAN message by using kvaser CAN-USB connector?

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I am trying to read the data coming from one device with the CAN communication protocol. I am using the Kvaser CAN-USB connector and python-can, but after sending the message I get the following:

Here's the my code:

```
import can
import time

bus=can.interface.Bus(bustype='kvaser',channel=0, bitrate=250000)
print (bus)
time.sleep(1)
msg =can.Message(arbitration_id=0x032)
print(msg)
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    bus.send(msg)
    recvMsg = bus.recv(timeout=0.5)
    print (recvMsg)
    time.sleep(1)
```

And here's the response i'm getting:

```
Kvaser Leaf Light v2, S/N 54781 (#1)

Timestamp:        0.000000    ID: 00000032    X                DLC:  0

Timestamp: 1546613346.010231        ID: 0000    S E              DLC:  4    00 01 00 00                 Channel: 0
```

According to the manual I have to use the following:

- Bitrate: 250 kbs
- 11-bit identifier: 0x031
- Default settings TX only
- 8 byte message structure:
  Byte:1,
  Description:State of charge [%],
  Type: Unsigned char,
  Value: 0-200 LSB = 0.5 % SOC.

This is my first time I use this communication protocol and I have read the python-can 3.0 description, but still is not clear to me how to solve the problem. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

ID: 0000  indicates an error frame!

In the script you set the arbitration_id=0x032, but the manual says
11-bit identifier: 0x031

is that a typo?

How does your network look like? How many nodes do you have?

Have you terminated the CAN bus?

Is there any reason why you do not use [PyCANlib](https://www.kvaser.com/download/?utm_source=software&utm_ean=7330130981911&utm_status=latest) from Kvaser?